# azure monitor action rule create fails with rule type ActionGroup via CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-monitoring, azure-cli2

Bug description:
Getting an issue, while trying to create a "azure monitor action rule" with "ActionGroup" as rule type using Azure CLI.
No specific parameter to pass "action group id" when rule-type is passed as ActionGroup.
What is the name of the parameter that should be used to pass the "action group id".

Steps To Reproduce:
Run the below CLI command to reproduce the issue.
az monitor action-rule create --name "actrule-001" --resource-group "rg-dev-001" --status Enabled --rule-type ActionGroup --severity Equals Sev0 --scope-type ResourceGroup --scope /subscription/xyz/resourceGroups/rg-dev-001

Below is the error while running the command:
Validation Error: Parameter "ActionGroup.action_group_id" can not be None.

Expected behavior:
CLI documentation is not clear how to pass the action group id, when we pass the rule type as "ActionGroup"

Environment summary:
CLI version 2.5.1 / OS version - Windows 10/ Shell Type - Bash on Windows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the latest update here for benefiting others in the community with similar asks:

Using `ActionGroup` as the `--rule-type` is not supported yet in the `alertsmanagement` extension. The initial release of the extension supports some of the most commonly used commands for now.

Since multiple customers have requested for this feature, our Product groups are prioritizing the implementation, with ETA being the end of November 2020.

Please track the feature request here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14163